# How do I get a list of redirect urls from Dell.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, python-requests

I am working on a web scraping project and want to get a list of products from Dell's website. I found this link (https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/products/) which pulls up a box with a list of product categories (really just redirect urls. If it doesn't come up for you click the button which says "Browse all products"). I tried using Python Requests to GET the page and save the text to a file to parse through, but the response doesn't contain any of the categories/redirect urls. My code is as basic as it gets:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/products/"
page = requests.get(url)

with open("laptops.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outf:
    outf.write(page.text)
    outf.close()
```

Is there a way to get these redirect urls? I am essentially trying to make my own site map of their products so that I can scrape the details of each one. Thanks

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then you can't get it with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`  because they can't run JavaScript. You may have to use `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you can check in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome (tab: Network) if javascript read data from other URL and then you can use this url with requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to get and display these links - but `requests`/`urllib` and `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` can't run `JavaScript`.

Using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`) I found it reads it from url

https://www.dell.com/support/components/productselector/allproducts?category=all-products/esuprt_&country=pl&language=pl&region=emea&segment=bsd&customerset=plbsd1&openmodal=true&_=1589265310743

so I use it to get links.

You may have to to change `country=pl&language=pl` in url to get it in different language.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://www.dell.com/support/components/productselector/allproducts?category=all-products/esuprt_&country=pl&language=pl&region=emea&segment=bsd&customerset=plbsd1&openmodal=true&_=1589265310743"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('a')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text, item['href'])
```

---

**BTW:** Other method is it use `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

try using selenium chrome driver it helps for handling dynamic data on website and also features like clicking buttons, handling page refresh etc.

[Beginner guide to web scraping](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72)